# Under windows , we frequently use event to coordinate threads, under java, is there any equivalent mechanism?

Tags: java

Under windows , we frequently use event to synchronize threads. Under java, is there anything equivalent?

Comment: So Windows is the new programming language?

Comment: @ThomasJungblut:You are right.I think he means .NET programming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure.
You can use [EventObjects](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/EventObject.html) and pass them to e.g. [blocking queue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) and consume events as they are generated.

E.g. read about EDT and Swing

Comment: any detailed steps to follow?

Comment: Sure, as soon as you have a detailed question :)